# Custom UITableViewCell subview layout

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitableview

I'm creating a custom `UITableViewCell`, similar in style to `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` but with an editable text field on the right side instead of the `detailTextLabel`.  I'm a little confused on how to size the edit field properly.  I want to take the length of the `textLabel` into account, as well as the size of the `contentView`, and be able to do the Right Thing when its table view is in edit mode, or if an accessory view (like a disclosure arrow) is added.

But the width of the `contentView` seems to always be 320 (on iPhone in portrait mode) even for a grouped table.  Within my `UITableViewCell` subclass, I see no way to get access to the table view to which it belongs so I can get the style of the table and adjust the margins accordingly.

I figure I can handle this in a custom fashion in the tableView's delegate `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method, but that completely defeats the purpose of having a reusable cell class.

I must be missing some key concept here, but I'm at a loss.  Anyone?

Thanks!
randy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to take control of your layout in your UITableViewCell subclass. For example:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGRect b = [self bounds];
    b.size.width += 30; // allow extra width to slide for editing
    b.origin.x -= (self.editing) ? 0 : 30; // start 30px left unless editing
    [contentView setFrame:b];
    // then calculate (NSString sizeWithFont) and addSubView, the textField as appropriate...
    // 
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Comment: I was missing the [super layoutSubviews]; that pre-sized things for me.  Thanks, Jordan.

Answer (score 0):

I think the margins are part of the cell, not the table, so that's why the contentView is always 320 wide. Maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: If the table view is plain style, visually the cell takes up the entire width of the table.  However, in the grouped style, *visually*, there is a 10 pixel margin on either side.  Inside the cell subclass, though, how do I determine whether or not to use this additional 10 pixel margin on either side?

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure. Try checking the `indendationLevel` or `indentationWidth`, they might be different on grouped vs. plain.